# Как преобразовать json строку в массив?

Tags: java, json

Я пытаюсь преобразовать json строку из файла в массив. Перешел из php, и в php все делается одной строкой.

```php
$langs = json_decode($json, true);
```

Но я столько информации облазил в интернете, что так до сих пор и не понял, как в Java получить данные именно с названием индекса и данные в нем, ибо они все уникальные.

Json файл представляет собой такой вид и состоит из 4000 строк с уникальными индексами, и каждый указывать не решение проблемы. Вот некоторый фрагмент:

```json
{
"GILDED_BLACKSTONE":"Золочёный чернит",
"NETHER_BRICK_SLAB":"Плита из преисподникового кирпича",
"ANDESITE_SLAB":"Плита из андезита",
"EGG":"Яйцо",
"MUSIC_DISC_STAL":"Пластинка",
"POTTED_WARPED_FUNGUS":"Искажённый гриб в горшке",
"PIGLIN_BRUTE_SPAWN_EGG":"Яйцо призыва свиновоина-чемпиона",
"BIRCH_STAIRS":"Ступеньки из берёзы",
"SPRUCE_SIGN":"Табличка из ели",
"DRAGON_HEAD":"Голова дракона",
"GREEN_DYE":"Зелёный краситель",
"HONEY_BLOCK":"Блок мёда",
"DIAMOND_ORE":"Алмазная руда",
"DEBUG_STICK":"Палочка отладки",
"SPRUCE_FENCE_GATE":"Калитка из ели",
"BLACK_STAINED_GLASS_PANE":"Чёрная стеклянная панель",
"AZURE_BLUET":"Хоустония голубая",
"SLIME_BALL":"Сгусток слизи",
"RABBIT":"Сырая крольчатина"
}
```

Мне нужно в отдельных переменных получить и название индекса и само значение этого элемента.
Эти данные мне нужно будет перебрать в будущем с помощью цикла.
Должно получиться что-то в этом роде:

```
for(здесь перебор элементов){
System.out.print(здесь название индекса);
System.out.print(здесь само значение элемента под этим индексом);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить через `Map`

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "\"GILDED_BLACKSTONE\":\"Золочёный чернит\",\n" +
                "\"NETHER_BRICK_SLAB\":\"Плита из преисподникового кирпича\",\n" +
                "\"ANDESITE_SLAB\":\"Плита из андезита\",\n" +
                "\"EGG\":\"Яйцо\",\n" +
                "\"MUSIC_DISC_STAL\":\"Пластинка\",\n" +
                "\"POTTED_WARPED_FUNGUS\":\"Искажённый гриб в горшке\",\n" +
                "\"PIGLIN_BRUTE_SPAWN_EGG\":\"Яйцо призыва свиновоина-чемпиона\",\n" +
                "\"BIRCH_STAIRS\":\"Ступеньки из берёзы\",\n" +
                "\"SPRUCE_SIGN\":\"Табличка из ели\",\n" +
                "\"DRAGON_HEAD\":\"Голова дракона\",\n" +
                "\"GREEN_DYE\":\"Зелёный краситель\",\n" +
                "\"HONEY_BLOCK\":\"Блок мёда\",\n" +
                "\"DIAMOND_ORE\":\"Алмазная руда\",\n" +
                "\"DEBUG_STICK\":\"Палочка отладки\",\n" +
                "\"SPRUCE_FENCE_GATE\":\"Калитка из ели\",\n" +
                "\"BLACK_STAINED_GLASS_PANE\":\"Чёрная стеклянная панель\",\n" +
                "\"AZURE_BLUET\":\"Хоустония голубая\",\n" +
                "\"SLIME_BALL\":\"Сгусток слизи\",\n" +
                "\"RABBIT\":\"Сырая крольчатина\"\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> map;
        map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {
        });
        map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
    }

}
```